# Center align Bootstrap dropdown menu with respect to Parent menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand there are several posts with the same title.But none of them work so well for me.

My testing url : [URL](http://thecybriainc-001-site14.smarterasp.net/)

I have already built the menu here, using Bootstrap 3.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the dropdown should be center align.

What have I tried so far:

```
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu{
 left : -50%;
}
```

But it is pushing the menu to extreme left.

The dropdown menu is currently align to left. Can anybody let me know why a `left: -50%` value pushing it to extreme left which actually should not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , a combination of

```
left: 50% !Important;
transform: translate(-50%) !important;
```

works !! Thanks !!

Comment: Er... Not a good idea to use those two, that too with `!important`. Consider using `margin-top` and `margin-left`, instead.

Comment: I am talking about center aligning the dropdown menu with respect to parent element. Hence no where , margin-top property will comes into play here. I tried out with margin-left and it did not work.  Please let me know if you get any other ideas .

Comment: Swapna, that's because of specificity. Please have a look at my answer. Your answer will not work in IE. I know what you are talking about. Check out mine.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following CSS for the rule:

```css
#navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -91px;
}
```

The reason is:

- Width of dropdown menu = `182px`.
- Keeping `left: 50%` will make it start at the centre.
- From the centre, it has to travel half its `width`, which is `91px`.

**Note:** You *may* put the `!important` to the `left` if it doesn't work, but that would be a temporary fix.